# Add a text file to an issue using MantisConnect

Tags: java, mantis

I'm using MantisConnect & Java to feed my bugtracker with issues. Does anyone know how to add attachments, like text files etc. ?

Mikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

First you create an issue object and add it to your session object. Afterwards you can add an attachment too. This looks something like:

```
IIssue issue = session.newIssue();
session.addIssue(issue); 
File file = new File(PathToYourAttachment);
LocalFileIssueAttachment attachment = new LocalFileIssueAttachment(file);
session.addIssueAttachment(session.getBiggestIssueId(projects[0].getId()), filename, attachment.getContentType(), attachment.getData());
```